# ASP.NET Image Rotation with Resolution

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, using

I am stuck up in a situation When I rotate Vertical Images and Set Resolution it works perfectly, but when I just Set resolution and delete and save the image it says "cant save..the Image file is being used". Help me out. Below is the code.

```vb
                 For cc As Integer = 0 To files1.Count - 1
                    Try
                        Dim _current As Bitmap
                        _current = DirectCast(Bitmap.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, files1.Item(cc).Name)), Bitmap)
                        Dim temp As Bitmap = DirectCast(_current, Bitmap)
                        Dim bmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(_current.Clone(), Bitmap)

                        If _current.Height > _current.Width Then
                             bmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX)
                        End If

                        _current = DirectCast(bmap.Clone(), Bitmap)
                        _current.SetResolution(200.0F, 200.0F)

                        temp.Dispose()
                        bmap.Dispose()

                        If System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, files1.Item(cc).Name)) Then
                            System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, files1.Item(cc).Name))
                            _current.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, files1.Item(cc).Name), ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                        End If
                        _current.Dispose()

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Return False
                    End Try
                Next
```

Comment: Could you fix the formatting on your code sample? When you declare temp, you're just DirectCasting _current (unnecessary, BTW since it's already a Bitmap).  When you declare bmp, you're cloning _current.  There may be something there causing the issue.  And what's up with the unused random integer?

Comment: Thanks for you quick Answer. Code in IF block works find But in ELSE Part i am using same code except RotateFlip. Could you please bring more light to it or correct my code ..Sir!!

Comment: I assume the error happens on the Save or the Delete and it's complaining because something has the file open preventing it from replacing it.  Try eliminating your `temp` variable. You can do it all with `bmp`.  Then your `if` can just be the rotation line.  Everything after that should be the same in both cases and doesn't need to be in the `if` or an `else`.

Comment: I did eliminate Unnecessary code but If i remove temp and use just bmap then IF block also says "Cant Delete. The file is being used error"

Comment: Does Bitmap.FromFile keep the file open until it's bitmap is disposed?  I wouldn't think so, but it's kind of acting like is.

Comment: Not really, if this was the case it would act same in IF block. Code works well if i use "bmap.RotateFlip" in all cases.